# Why do browsers always ask to update Java?

Tags: browser, java

I have all my browsers asking to update Java, for example, if this link open http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html

If I agree to update, this does not help.

Is this common market situation? Or this is my system glitch?

Comment: What update do you have installed, what update is being offered, you provided none of this information

Comment: Useful sites: http://mozilla.org/plugincheck (This checks whether plugins are up to date; works on most browsers, not just Mozilla ones. Note that many plugins are shared between browsers, so do one browser at a time.) http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp (Checks Java specifically, and also gives tips on how to remove old versions.)

Answer (score 7):

All of your browsers are asking to update Java because your Java has updates available.

Those updates close security holes that allow a remote website to infect your computer with viruses, that is why your browser specifically is reminding you that you need to perform the update.

Find what editions of java you have installed and either uninstall them if you don't need them or get the latest versions from the Java website.

Comment: This is not true: I always agree to update and have latest Java. May be browsers see some older ones? How browser selects Java if multiple ones installed?

Comment: If you have multiple versions installed uninstall the older versions. You are still vulnerable to infections if you have older versions available on your computer. Also agreeing to the update does not guarantee that the update succeeds. I have the worst luck with the java auto updater and have to manually download it for it to work with my machine.

Comment: If it is continuing to ask you to update, it didn't install correctly.  You may try uninstalling from Program and Features, and then reinstalling, or resetting Internet Explorer and any related browsers.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Agreeing to update is insufficient. You need to check what Java software you have installed, check if it's current, install the current versions of anything that's not, and then remove the obsolete versions. There are serious security risks which is why everything is pestering you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You receive an alert to update Java because either:

- Java is outdated,
- An update wasn't installed properly, thus Java remains outdated, or
- It is a malware faking a Java update request.

Also note that usually the update alert comes *not from the browser, but from Java itself*, via a taskbar icon similar to this one:

[image]

It is possible that in some sites, the Java application requires some specific version of Java to be running, but in this case it would be the site, rather than the browser, alerting of an outdated Java version.

Answer (score -1):

The issue we routinely see is that websites using the browser java plug-ins do not necessarily support the latest versions.  Unfortunately the incremental updates actual change the behavior of the Java engine (for better or worst).  3rd party developers then need time to develop updates to adapt to the new behavior and may only include it in future enhancements of their product.

If a end-user follows the on-screen recommendation to install the latest version, these websites break.  It then becomes an IT issue to remove the update and re-install the compatible version.  IT administrators should have a direct path for eliminating the "Install Now" pop-up as distribution is usually controlled with AD Group Policy or some other distribution software.

Comment: Although the information you shared is valid, I can't see how this answers the question.